# How do I add padding without affecting container?

Tags: css

I am redesigning the login page for an open source software ([Fedena](http://demo.projectfedena.org/)). These are [my changes](http://arcube.com.ng:8088). As you can see, I am using background icons in the username/password fields. Currently, text entered into the field overlaps the icons and I'm looking for a way to avoid this.

When I add a padding-left of say 30px to one of the fields, it corrects the problem (puts the cursor in front of the icon), but it also expands the width of the field. How can I successfully insert the required padding without extending the box?

Comment: You can use the CSS property ``box-sizing`` setting it to ``border-box`` Take a look http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: @JoãoMosmann That took care of it. Thank you :) If you're willing to post that as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as an accepted solution to help others searching.

Comment: Ok @n3rve! I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the CSS property `box-sizing`.

Setting this to `border-box`. It will count the padding and the border as part of the width.

So, in the example below. The width and height of the element will continue being `100px` even with the `25px` padding and `1px` border

```
.my-input-element {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS to your component, for example:
`div { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }`